# how to correctly set Fragment?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

i'm studing how set correctly fragment in my activity.
Android studio says that android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager() and android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction are Deprecated. I would like understand what's the right way to use androidx librarys to set correctly the fragment.
Here my code that works with deprecated warning.

```
main_activity.java
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

        FragmentTransaction tx = fm.beginTransaction();

        //TODO Aggiungere il FragmentUno
        FragmentUno fragmentUno = new FragmentUno();
        tx.add(R.id.fragment_place, fragmentUno);
        tx.commit();


    }

    public void selFtrag(View view) {

        Fragment frID;
        if(view == findViewById(R.id.btnGoku)){
        frID = new FragmentUno();
        }else{
            frID =new FragmentDue();
        }
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction tx =fm.beginTransaction();

        tx.replace(R.id.fragment_place, frID);
        tx.commit();
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: i suggest you to use navigation fragment navigation

Comment: I presume you've read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)? What issues did you have with it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [migration](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) of Android Studio. **Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX**

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this resources :-

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

Instead of..

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

Comment: sure but, if i use it, i think it's not possible to use FragmentManager because i've a message that it's no longer supported by androidx resources

Comment: Then check [android developers documentations](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)